# Get position (in number) of selected item in dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

In a dropdown list I have a few items. Can I, when I select an item, get the position of that item in the list as a number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a list or combo box, `ListIndex` would seem to be what you are after.

VB Help for `ListIndex` property: Returns or sets the index number of the currently selected item in a list box or combo box. Read/write Long.  Remarks. You cannot use this property with multiselect list boxes.

If nothing is selected, `ListIndex`'s value is `-1`.  If memory serves, it is a zero based index.

`ListIndex` cannot be set at design time so it is not listed in the properties window.

When entering your code, type the list box name then dot and the editor displays all the available properties.  Scroll down the list, note any that look interesting, then look them up.

Comment: That was it. I knew it was a simple function, but I couldn't find it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for the index of a Data Validation list, this is what I'd do:

Put the following code in the ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ValidationIndex As Long
Dim rngTest As Excel.Range

'assumes the data validation is in a cell named "rngTest"
On Error Resume Next
Set rngTest = Sh.Range("rngTest")
If rngTest Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Sh.Range("rngTest")) Is Nothing Then
    ValidationIndex = GetValidationIndex
    MsgBox ValidationIndex
End If
End Sub
```

Put this function in the ThisWorkbook module also, or else in any regular module:

```
Function GetValidationIndex() As Long
'returns a 1-based index
Dim rngTest As Excel.Range
Dim varValidationString As Variant
Dim ErrNumber As Long
Dim i As Long

With ActiveCell.Validation
    If .Type = xlValidateList Then    '3
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngTest = ActiveCell.Parent.Range(.Formula1)
        'I do this goofy thing with ErrNumber to keep my indenting and flow pretty
        ErrNumber = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        'if the Validation is defined as a range
        If ErrNumber = 0 Then
            GetValidationIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value2, rngTest, 0)
            Exit Function
        'if the validation is defined by comma-separated values
        Else
            varValidationString = Split(.Formula1, ",")
            For i = LBound(varValidationString) To UBound(varValidationString)
                If varValidationString(i) = ActiveCell.Value2 Then
                    GetValidationIndex = i + 1
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: @ Jean-François Corbett Thanks!  I was pretty sure it wasn't what the OP wanted, and can't think of a practical use, but it was fun to write.

Comment: This is great, but it fails if there's more than one identical member of the group in the pulldown. It just gives you the number of the first of the identical members, not the one you actually clicked. I need to solve this to resolve a many-to-one issue in someone else's design.

Comment: @James, I'll take a look later, but I don't think so.  More important, I think it's a design flaw to offer the user two identical choices.  How do they know which identical choice to pick in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not necessary to use a function. You can get it by using only Match function, like in above Doug's answer.

```
Dim GetValidationIndex as Integer
Dim rngTest as Range      
' Get the validation list
With ActiveCell.Validation
   Set rngTest = ActiveCell.Parent.Range(.Formula1)
end with

GetValidationIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value2, rngTest, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `GetValidationIndex` is good.

However, for some regional settings the line `varValidationString = Split(.Formula1, ",")` is not valid, because the character used to separate the different values is `";"`

I suggest use:

```
varValidationString = Split(.Formula1, Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the validation list from a separate hidden sheet, and have a column next to it that provides the index number. Then there are several ways to get that index number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).