# How to use VBA to select the first iterm in a drop down list in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I used Data Validation to create some drop down lists. Anyone know how to use VBA to select the first iterm in a drop down list?

I tried 'Split' function:

```
cell.Value = Split(cell.Validation.Formula1, ",")(0)
```

but it did not work well, it will only work if I put like "option1, option2" in the source in Data Validation window. If I refer the source to a range of options, then it will return with errors.

I guess there should some smarter ways.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here? Are you using some kind of combo box object? Could you give us an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: You could perhaps modify my answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8458071/293078)

Comment: replace "," with ";".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim adr As String
    With Range("c4")
        adr = Mid(.Validation.Formula1, 2)
        Debug.Print Range(adr).Cells(1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

so your answer is:

`set c = range("c4")

c.Value = Range(Mid(c.Validation.Formula1, 2)).Cells(1, 1).Value`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried, it didn't work. There was no error, but the drop down list did not select the first item, instead, it just kept what is used to be.

Comment: I tried on my pc and it filled the cell C4...I used "c" instead of  "cell" as a variable because "cell" looks like a reserved word = asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried. It worked fine for the cells with data validation refering to a range of options. But it doesn't work fine for those that I put "option1, option2" in the source in data validation. Is there any way to solve that? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you will to use the split option for those with a list, and the Range().Cells() option for those with a range...

Comment: I think so, but is there a way to say like: if xxx then xxx, else if xxx then xxx? I don't know how to set the condition here. Thanks! We are almost there

Comment: Use Instr() to test if `.Validation.Formula1` contains a ":" ? If true, it's a range.