# Auto select a value from a drop down list based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the value of a drop down list based on the value of another cell.
Is there a formula that can do this?
Thanks

Comment: I have tried doing an if formula but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you find anything posted useful? Please post feedback, vote and/or accept according to what you found.

Answer (score 0):

Make the list reference a range, populate that range with formulas that are reliant on formulas generated from the cell that can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Worksheet.Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).
Assuming the cell controlling the value of the drop down list is A1, and the drop down list is in A2, put the following code (not tested) in the VBA module for your Sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    If ( Target.Address = "$A$1" ) Then
        Dim ddlrng as Range
        Set ddlrng = Range( "A2" )
        Dim frm as String
        frm = ddlrng.Validation.Formula1
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is <value1>
                ' Change A2 to some value in the list
            Case ...
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

The way to change the value of the drop down list depends on `frm`.
See
[How to use VBA to select the first iterm in a drop down list in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126636/how-to-use-vba-to-select-the-first-iterm-in-a-drop-down-list-in-excel)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8458711/2707864

Comment: Fantastic! i will try it now and let you know how i go

Comment: @NikkiC - Please note that you will have to work a little bit to come up with a working code. I have given you something more than the required skeleton, and the guidelines for completing it.