# VBA Reset all Checkbox,ComboBox, Text box and Data validation Dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm very new to Visual Basics and I'm trying to reset the comboboxes to the first index, dropdownlist to the first index and reset all checkboxes and textboxes.

But I'm having trouble reseting the data validation drop down list and combo boxes back to their first index/value.

Sheet3

[image]
DND

[image]
Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A2:DE2").Copy
Sheets("Final").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    For Each Sh In Sheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Sh.CheckBoxes.Value = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next Sh
    Dim tbx As OLEObject
    For Each tbx In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(tbx.Object) = "TextBox" Then
        tbx.Object.Text = ""
        End If
    Next

    Range("Sheet3!C2").Value = ""
    Sheets("DND").Range("A17").Value = 0
    Sheets("DND").Range("C17").Value = 0


End Sub
```

Comment: This answer of mine might give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8458711/293078

Comment: @DougGlancy I'm very new to Excel VBA so I'm not quite sure where to copy and paste your code.  I've copied the first code in my `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange` method but how do I integrate your code to make it so when I press a button `CommandButton1_Click()` It'll set the data validation drop down list to the first index(Which is a blank space)

Comment: I'll see if I can work something up.

Comment: @DougGlancy I've uploaded my code ! I just need the data validation to work since I can reset my other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks whether the data validation in L6 of the active sheet is a hardcoded list or a range reference. It then either resets the cell to the first list item or the first cell in the range reference:

```
Sub ResetCellValidation()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim rngTest As Excel.Range
Dim ErrNumber As Long

Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("L6")
With cell.Validation
    If .Type = xlValidateList Then    
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngTest = Application.Range(.Formula1)
        'I do this goofy thing with ErrNumber to keep my indenting and flow pretty
        ErrNumber = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        'if the Validation is defined as a range
        If ErrNumber = 0 Then
            cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngTest, 1)
        'if the validation is defined by comma-separated values
        Else
            cell.Value = Split(.Formula1, ",")(0)
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

There's no error-checking to confirm that there's any data validation in that cell, but not sure that could be an issue the way you're using it.

EDIT: Changed it from Activecell.Parent.Range(.Formula1) to Application.Range(.Formula1). Interestingly, for example, if Formula1 is `Sheet2!E6`, the above evaluates the full address. Don't know if I ever knew that.

EDIT 2: I think I've really overthought this, or didn't adjust to the facts as they became clearer. If you just want to set the cell value back to blank, this one line of code will do it:

`ActiveSheet.Range("L6").Value = ""`

But where's the fun in that?

Comment: I copied the whole code except `Sub ResetCellValidation()` and `End Sub` into my `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` but it doesn't do anything. The button runs but my data validation drop down list stays the same. Note: It should be "C17" but "L6" right? since my data validation drop down list is on  L6

Comment: Yes you should change it to L6. Is the sheet with the Data Validation the active one when you run this? When you step through with F8 (look it up if you don't know how) does it make it to one of the lines that starts with `cell.Value = `?

Comment: So my Data validation is on Sheet3 but my list of values (Spray Operator, Edger, Office) is on a sheet called "DND" starting at B2 to B15. Yes my button is on Sheet3 which is where my data validation drop down list is.

Comment: It actually works but for some reason it always sets the value when I click the button back to Spray Operator(DND!B6) when it should be a blank space (DND!B2) (I've uploaded a picture of my DND sheet)

Comment: Imagine for a second that you are me and wonder what you would say or ask in response to your last comment :-). What information - besides those rather random-sounding IDs - might you need in order to help me? Hint: where they are stored and the order they're in.

Comment: I've uploaded some pictures maybe that would help?

Comment: Sorry, I see that you'd already told me where your values are from. So what range do you specify in your data validation? Is it DND!B2:B15?

Comment: They are in DND!$B$2:$B$15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109492/discussion-between-doug-glancy-and-tykimikk).