# Create ComboBox in Excel cells

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I want to create a Select or Drop-down List or ComboBox (whatever you want to call it).

I do not want to do it with UserForm because it displays a window on the cells and I want it in the cells. **Example (See image)**

[image]

I want when selecting **PERRO** in the combobox the cell shows the number 1, if it is **GATO** the cell shows the number 2, if it is **VACA** the cell shows the number 3.

Comment: If you want it "in" the cells that is data validation. Not sure you can return the index of an item from a given list.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of:  get position in number of selected item in dropdown-list  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458071/get-position-in-number-of-selected-item-in-dropdown-list See answer by 
Doug Glancy

Comment: you can probably use just Data Validation drop-down list, and a lookup Excel function like       `=Match(A1, {"PERRO", "GATO", "VACA"}, 0)`

Comment: @Slai How would this work in the same cell? I am genuinely interested as I couldn't think of a way. Having a helper column with a Match formula to return the index and setting the data validation cell to white font was the best I could think of.

Comment: @QHarr I am guessing the 1, 2, 3 are used in another formula

Comment: I solved this with the answer of @Eric Capnu Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options

1. Use Data Validation (DATA>DATA TOOLS>DATA VALIDATION) as you showed in the image, but you'll have to combine it with VLOOKUP function (kinda painful)
2. Attach a Combobox Form Control (DEVELOPER>CONTROLS>INSERT) right click and go to format control. From here, you can assign a source list and a result cell in numeric format. I mean if you select Perro, since it is the first element, the result cell give the value 1. It is the best way for me.

[image]

3. Finally, you can use a Combobox ActiveX Control (DEVELOPER>CONTROLS>INSERT), you can add the elements from the properties windows or VBA script by using the method AddItem

For example:

```
With ComboBox
  .AddItem "perro"
  .AddItem "gato"
  .AddItem "vaca"
  .AddItem "cerdo"
End With
```

and you can create a result cell with a conditional

```
Select Case Combobox.value
  Case "perro": range("a1")=1
  Case "gato": range("a1")=2
  Case "vaca": range("a1")=3
  Case "cerdo": range("a1")=4
End Select
```

That would be easy for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks man the second option help me to solve my problem so easy.

Answer (score 0):

other then the solution by the link provided by QHarr in the comments, you could try a totally VBA solution, with the code making the validation list appear every time the user selects the wanted cell

to do so you have to:

- delete and placing back the validation rules at every cell selection
- substitute list item select with its index in the list

so you need to deal with both `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` and `Worksheet_Change()` event handlers

place the following code in the worksheet code pane

```
Option Explicit

Dim animals As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then ' if selected cell is the wanted one (change "$B$2" to any wanted address
        Dim element As Variant
        Dim position As Long
        For Each element In animals 'loop through validation list
            position = position + 1 'update index position
            If element = Target.Value Then 'if current loop element matches cell content
                Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent subsequent sheet change (deleting and writing cell content) fire this event again and start an infinite loop
                Target.Validation.Delete 'remove data validation
                Target.Value = position ' write the element index position
                Application.EnableEvents = True 'restore proper event handling
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then ' if selected cell is the wanted one (change "$B$2" to any wanted address
        With Target
            If hasValidation(.Cells) Then
                .ClearContents 'clear any previous cell content
            Else
                animals = Array("Perro", "Gato", "Vaca", "Cerdo") 'set the validation list
                .ClearContents 'clear any previous cell content
                With .Validation 'set validation rules
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(animals, ",")
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub


Function hasValidation(rng As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    hasValidation = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Cells.Count = 1
End Function
```