# Obtaining the Index Number of a Drop-Down List

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

In short, I am trying to get the index number of a drop-down list through VBA. In this case, the drop-down list is created via data validation.

Long story, I have created a simple worksheet that contains a few drop-down lists that were made through data validation, which contains strings only.

Depending on the user selection, I would like to then perform some tasks depending on the selected option. Instead of inputting the entire string into a select case or an if-else then statement, getting the index number of the selected option of that particular drop-down list would be a much more efficient way of doing it.

I am aware of the ListIndex property which function fits my exact requirement, but as far as I'm aware, it is only applicable to listbox and combobox.

I am also aware of another similar question raised:
[Get position (in number) of selected item in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458071/get-position-in-number-of-selected-item-in-dropdown-list).
This solution however does not work for me and results in a returned value of "0" in most cases when selecting options other than the first item in the drop down list. From my shallow understanding in VBA, it seems to only function as expected when there are no repeating words between the various drop-down options.

I would also greatly appreciate it if anyone could elaborate on the solution code as I would like to understand what exactly is going on and grow my knowledge on VBA programming.

Comment: "the drop-down list is created via conditional formatting" - do you mean data validation?  Would help to explain *exactly* how you created your lists.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yup, it is data validation. Pardon the incorrect terminologies used.

Comment: How did you add the list exactly?

Comment: @TimWilliams Selecting a desired cell > Under Data Validation > Settings > Allow: List > Under Source: String 1, String 2, etc. > OK

Comment: Seems like Doug's answer at your linked post should work fine?  Or do you have repeated items in your list?  If Yes then I'm not sure there's any solution (though I can't think why you'd have duplicates...)

Comment: @TimWilliams Technically there are duplicates, but only a/ few words within a string. Example list:
1. Unshielded cable
2. Shielded cable

The repeating word "cable" here seems to throw off the logic of Doug's answer, resulting in returned value of "0" instead of "2" when selecting "Shielded cable".

Comment: Doug's code checks the full cell value against each value in the list, so it shouldn't result in wrong values from a partial match?  Did you try my code below?  That worked fine for me.

Comment: @TimWilliams I believe it could be that I'm somehow executing/ placing the function incorrectly. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as per Doug's instructions, the first half of the code is to be placed under ThisWorkbook module, with the function itself into there too or any regular module. Once done, I should be expecting a message box to appear displaying the index number whenever I select an option within a drop-down list, is that correct?

Comment: So far I've only been able to get the response as mentioned in the post via selecting the cell that contains a selected drop-down and running the function directly using "Debug.Print GetValidationIndex" under the immediate tab, with the function part of the code under a module.

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly how you want to do this - what triggers finding the index, and how is any specific cell being identified?  Are you using a worksheet event or ???

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me - similar to Doug's answer at your linked post.

```vb
Sub tester()

    Debug.Print SelectedListIndex([F1])

End Sub



'If `c` has a list-based validation (from direct entry, not a range reference)
'  and a value has been selected, return the index of the value in the list
Function SelectedListIndex(c As Range)
    Dim arr, m, v
    m = -1
    v = c.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        If Not c.Validation Is Nothing Then
            If c.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
                arr = Split(c.Validation.Formula1, _
                            Application.International(xlListSeparator))
                m = Application.Match(c.Value, arr, 0)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    SelectedListIndex = IIf(IsError(m), -1, m)
End Function
```